# Custom bin and find how many samples fall into the bins using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset something like this

```
sample value
  A     0.2
  B     0.25
  C     0.51
  D     0.91
```

I would like to bin the data in the following custom bin of c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.9) and find out the freq of 'sample' falling in the bin. Using the new binned data, I would like to draw a histogram of values against the number of samples. Any help is appreciated to help me produce these custom bins

Comment: Try this `df$Cut <- cut(df$value,breaks = c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.9,Inf),include.lowest = T,right = T,dig.lab = 10)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `table`+ `cut`

```
bin <- c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.9)

> table(cut(df1$value,c(bin,Inf)))

  (0,0.25] (0.25,0.5] (0.5,0.75] (0.75,0.9]  (0.9,Inf] 
         2          0          1          0          1
```

or `hist`

```
> hist(df1$value,breaks = c(bin,Inf), plot = FALSE)
$breaks
[1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 0.90  Inf

$counts
[1] 2 0 1 0 1

$density
[1] 2 0 1 0 0

$mids
[1] 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.825   Inf

$xname
[1] "df1$value"

$equidist
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
```

Comment: Many thanks. All the above worked. I made the histogram with the output ('df1') usin above methods, like so, hist(as.numeric(df1$value),plot = TRUE)